# Issue outputting data from vectors of different sizes

Tags: c++, vector, output

```
for(int i=1; i<distances.size(); i++)
cout << "Distance between " << names[i-1] << " and " << names[i] << " is: " << distances[i] << ", " << endl;
```

This is a snippet of my program, a quick bit of info:
The program takes input from the user to find out where they would like to visit and then prints(issue lies here) the distances between destinations. So all the calculations work, but the issue is with my cout line, because one distance is created for the first two inputs, and then one more distance for every other input. So in short, distances.size is 1 less than names.size. What this means is that no names are put out for the first distance recorded since I'm using 'i' to loop the output. If I enter 3 destinations, there is one output. 4 destinations, 2 outputs, but 2 destinations, there are no outputs. What can I do? I hope I've made my issue clear.

Comment: add the full program to get better sense of what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about your software Design...

I assume, that if you have 3 distances, you would want to know the distance from 1 to 2, and from 2 to 3, and 1 to 3 is irrelevant.

For a quick solution, just build yourself a simple struct that looks like that:

```
struct....
{
   CDestination dest1;
   CDestination dest2;

   float Distance;

   Calculate()
   {
    Distance = /* Your calculation here */
   }  
}
```

Not just create a vector of those structs and print the three members. Sorry if thats not what you want, but you didn't provide that much code or information about your problem.....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is already a struct like this: struct City{string name; double x; double y;}

Comment: And you were correct to assume I am interested in those distances, I also have a total distance calculated. The issue is that in order to output the distances using distances[i], i has to equal 0 and will always be one less than names.size

Comment: yes, but where ths problem with my solution? Just put those structs into a vector and print the distances in a for loop from o to vec.size()?